# How to give symbolic name in Jetty Server

Tags: configuration, jetty

I have webapps in Jetty that has a symbolic link: myapp -> test. I have a file index.xml under the test directory.

I am able to read it through `http://hostname/test/index.xml`. 
But I want to read it as `http://hostname/myapp/index.xml`.

How should I configure the name for the app?

Comment: I'm also interested in a solution for this. Did you find an answer ?